# Jenkins 2.235.5 with Sonarqube - Invalid JSON String

Tags: jenkins

I recently updated my jenkins-blueocean to Jenkins 2.235.5. I am having problem with my pipeline step on getting the results of quality gate from my sonarqube server. I can still send my code for analysis but my jenkins can't read the JSON response which was working before the update. Please see below for the error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)
at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getCETask(WsClient.java:53)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.checkTaskCompleted(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:234)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:171)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor377.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may occur due to an invalid URL in the Jenkins configuration.

Make sure you that your sonarqube is valid and configured **without** trailing slash at:
Manage Jenkins -> SonarQube servers -> Server URL

Comment: Thank you @Ofir! It is now working after I change the server URL for sonarqube server. The trailing slash was there before I upgraded my Jenkins and it was working but I guess it won't work with the latest version. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Treaudian Please accept this as the answer if it helped you 
It did me :)

Comment: Oh!!! Apologies on that, I forgot to tick the checkbox! Though I already thanked @Ofir.... Thanks also for pointing out Faner.